# Distributed transactions with .NET Core running on Windows

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-core, transactionscope, distributed-transactions

I am aware that distributed transactions are not supported (as of yet) with .NET Core as it is platform independent. My question is since I plan to run this .NET Core service on Windows, whether it's possible to somehow use the implementation that say .NET Framework uses with MSDTC?

Currently I've only looked at targetting multiple frameworks, say `netcoreapp3.1` and `net48` and running it as `net48` but there are a ton of incompatibilities, e.g. most gRPC libraries. I am wondering if there is some other workaround to this issue.

Comment: It's certainly possible -- but it would be a lot of non-trivial work, which is exactly the reason .NET Core on Windows doesn't support it (yet). If what you're going for was fairly easy with some drop-in libraries the maintainers would adopt that solution -- distributed transactions are not being excluded for the *sole* reason they're Windows-only, as plenty of Windows-only technologies are now part of .NET Core (albeit with a platform check). I suspect the cross-project dependencies are the biggest problem (this technology ideally should not need to be part of the base library).

Comment: As far as I've read, Microsoft would need a separate DTC for every platform and for now they have chosen not to implement it. First it was targeted for 3.1, then 5.0, now it's set to 'Future'. In my situation, the only possible solution I can think of is to target `net48` but then it's an entire headache how to host a gRPC service and make use of it when the packages themselves don't target that framework. Thank you for the input anyways.